# How can I Insert an Umbraco Item in to a url in a cshtml file, razor?

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

I've made an If statement containing a youtube link.

In umbraco I have a Text String box that enables a user to insert the ID of a youtube video.

```
<div class="module m-video">
    <div class="regular">
        <div class="graphics video-container">
        <iframe width="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<umbraco:Item field="youtubeId" runat="server" />?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when the page loads it displays the `<umbraco:Item field="youtubeId" runat="server" />` instead of what the user put in.

What work around is their to display what a user inserts into the text string box.

*All must be done in razor*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a "YoutubeVideo" macro along with it's razor script "YoutubeVideo.cshtml". And that cshtml code would look like this:

```
@using umbraco.MacroEngines
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext

<div class="module m-video">
    <div class="regular">
        <div class="graphics video-container">
            <iframe width="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/@Model.youtubeId?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in your .master you could include that mascroscript like this:

```
<umbraco:Macro ID="Macro1" Alias="YoutubeVideo" runat="server" />
```

This approach may differ if you are using Umbraco 6+ with MVC, but otherwise this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this inside the umbraco template editor you should be able to swap the double quotes denoting the `src` attribute with single quotation marks, and the umbraco item needs no change.

```
<iframe width="100%" src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/<umbraco:Item field="youtubeId" runat="server" />?rel=0' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```